# How do I maintain user entered text in a TextBox nested in an UpdatePanel between updates?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have an ASP.Net UpdatePanel that updates on a timer.  Within the UpdatePanel and nested in a GridView, I have a TextBox that the user enters a value in with a submit button.  Everything works fine, except if the user does not submit the value before the timed interval, the text is removed from the TextBox.

Is there a way to persist the user entry into the TextBox between updates?  Is there a better way of doing this?

All suggestions welcome.

Respectfully,

Ray K. Ragan

Code Postscript:

aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequest);

    function beginRequest() {
        prm._scrollPosition = null;
    } 
</script> 

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="900" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DataList RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  ID="dlMine" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Item_Command">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="border:1px solid black;margin:3px;height:300px;text-align:center;padding:5px;">
                <div style="width:150px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# left(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"title").ToString(), 75) %>'></asp:Label>
                </div>   
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"end_date") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0:C}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"current_value")) %>'></asp:Label>
                    <br />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:Button Visible='<%# (isInThePast((DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"end_date"))) ? false : true %>' CssClass="bid_button" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Revalue" ID="btnBid" Text="Submit New Valuation" />                  
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    </ContentTemplate>    
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Timer1_Tick);


                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    dataBindList();
                }
            }

            protected void dataBindList()
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["GroupID"] != null)//Are they coming here with a URL var? If so, build content object
                {
                    List<Item> itemList = ItemManager.getItemsByGroupID(Request.QueryString["GroupID"].ToString());

                    dlMine.DataSource = itemList.Take(15);
                    dlMine.DataBind();
                }
            }

            protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dataBindList();
                UpdatePanel1.Update();
            }

protected void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Revalue")
            {
                Person p = (Person)Session["Person"];

                foreach (DataListItem item in dlMine.Items)
                {


                    string textBoxText = ((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtNewValue")).Text;

                    Utilities.writeLog("txtNewValue: " + textBoxText, 1);

                }            


                dataBindList();
                UpdatePanel1.Update();
            }
        }
```

Comment: There should be something else affecting the text box on the postback. By default, the state of the textbox would be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rebinding the DataList every time the Timer ticks.  All changes in the ItemTemplates of the DataList will be lost on postback.

Why not use Javascript to "pause" the timer whenver one of the textboxes gains focus.  This will prevent the Timer from firing and let users finish entering text.  Once they leave the textbox of "onblur" then you can restart the timer.

**Update**

The following will take a bit of effort to make it happen but you can do something like:

- When the Timer posts back, before rebinding, iterate over the DataList while searching for textboxes with text in them.  Something like:

`foreach (DataListItem item in dlMine.Items)
{
   //find the textbox control and check for text
}`

- At this point, you'll know which rows need there textboxes repopulated. Store this information in a hashtable.

In the DataList ItemDataBound event, check each rowID against the hashtable to see if its corresponding textbox exists.  If so, repopulate the textbox in the DataList row.

Comment: I think that's close, but not quite what Ray wants: the user has to click `Submit` to commit the new text. Perhaps instead add a `Cancel` button that restarts the timer.

Comment: Fair enough but the timer is the problem here.  The timer onTick needs to cause data in the DataList to be posted back to the server and then used to repopulate on postback.  Otherwise, every time the timer post back, the data will be lost.

Comment: and @Jeff Sternal thank you both.  I experimented with pausing the timer with semi-satisfactory results.  I think I may need to resort to a qwerty solution here by presenting the user with a modal window on focus.  This will distract their attention away from the timer and present them with more information on the item.  Not exactly what I planned, but a good work-around in favor of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing the `TextBbox` value in your code-behind, perhaps in `Page_Load` or another page method?

```
TextBox1.Text = "";
```

If so, that code is executing on every timer event. You can prevent that like this:

```
if (! IsPostback) {
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

The first request that hits an ASP.NET page is usually an [HTTP GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods) request, while ASP.NET buttons and update panel events issue [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) requests. So the code above will clear `TextBox1` the first time you access the page, but leave the value alone when receiving requests from itself. (If you really are setting the text box's value to its default - empty - you could just remove the initialization code.)

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the response.  No, I'm not pre-poping the textboxes.  They are nested in the UpdatePanel, which has the GridView, which has the TextBox at the row level.  It works fine, except when the UpdatePanel updates on the timer, it resets the TextBox to blank despite the user's entry.  A UI flaw that will surely irritate users; I want happy users.

Comment: Are you initializing your `GridView`'s datasource in your code? That could be doing essentially the same thing I described in my answer. You may need to show us some of your code-behind code to properly diagnose this.

Comment: I think you're right; I didn't think of it in those terms.  I added my markup and codebehind, as I'm not sure how to overcome this behaviour.